# Maximum of a blackbody using Golden-section

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to find the maximum of the function of a blackbody with temperatures of 3000, 5000 and 7000, I have to do it with the golden-section search technique, I got the next error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

tried to solve it myself but couldn't. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
import math
#-blackbody---------------------------
k=1.38*(10**-23)    
h= 6.62607015e-34
c=3e8
def long (T,lam):
    x=(h*c)/(k*T*lam)
    c1=2*h*c**2
    plamb=c1/((np.exp(x)-1)*lam**5)
    return plamb
l=np.arange(1e-12,4e-6,1e-8)
#-golden-section-----------------------
gr=(math.sqrt(5)+1)/2
def gss(f,a,b,tol=1e-10):
    c=b-(b-a)/gr
    d=a+(b-a)/gr
    while abs(c-d)>tol:
          if f(c)<f(d):
             b=d
          else:
             a=c
          c=b-(b-a)/gr
          d=a+(b-a)/gr
    return (b+a)/2
q=long(3e3,l)
w=long(5e3,l)
e=long(7e3,l)
x=gss(q,1e-12,1e-5)
y=gss(w,1e-12,1e-5)
z=gss(e,1e-12,1e-5)
print('T=3000; %.15f'%x)
print('T=5000; %.15f'%y)
print('T=7000; %.15f'%z)
# using wien---------------------------
λq=0.00289/3e3
λw=0.00289/5e3
λe=0.00289/7e3
print('Max using Wien 3000 = %.10f'%λq)
print('Max using Wien 5000 = %.10f'%λw)
print('Max using Wien 7000 = %.10f'%λe)
#-plot----------------------------------
plt.plot(l*1e7,q,'r')
plt.plot(l*1e7,w,'b')
plt.plot(l*1e7,e,'g')
plt.ylabel('Intencity')
plt.xlabel('λ(m)     1e7')
plt.show()
```

Comment: "long" returns an array.  Therefore "q" is an array,  You pass q as the first argument to gss, so the variable "f" inside gss is an array.  Then you call it as if it were a function.- that's an error.  Protip: When python prints a traceback, look at it carefully to see which line in your program triggered the error.  When asking for help in SO, provide this information (or better yet, the whole traceback).  It saves a LOT of time.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'm trying to change that.